# How create ServletUpgradeRequest for Jetty WebSocketClient?

Tags: java, websocket, jetty, embedded-jetty

I would like to send additional information using ServletUpgradeRequest object. 
Jetty WebSocketClient have several versions of connect method some of them accept UpgradeRequest.

Question is how manually create this ServletUpgradeRequest object?

Answer (score 0):

RTM

```
        ClientUpgradeRequest request = new ClientUpgradeRequest();
        /*...
        ..*/
        client.connect(this, url, request);
```

Comment: Telling yourself to RTFM may not make the best thread, and code dumps aren't always that helpful to future readers. Consider completing your answer and adding details to what you have done.